# CSS: как обводку текста сделать жирнее?

Tags: html, css, outline

Делаю обводку текста с помощью text-shadow. Можно ли её сделать жирнее? У box-shadow есть отдельный параметр, отвечающий за жирность, а у text-shadow - только за размытие. Его увеличение желаемого эффекта не даёт.

Подскажите, какие могут быть варианты?

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 2px 0 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 2px 2px #8c1b21, 
    -2px 0 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 -2px 2px #8c1b21;
}
```

```html
<p>ОБВОДКА ТЕКСТА</p>
```

Comment: желаемый эффект надо показывать

Comment: на svg не вариант ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я просто svg не владею - если Вы покажете, как это будет выглядеть, возможно, подойдёт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант сделать больше наложений:

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 
    2px 2px 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 2px 2px #8c1b21, 
    -2px 0 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 -2px 2px #8c1b21/*, убираем 1 комментарий, получаем более жирную обводку    
    3px 3px 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 3px 2px #8c1b21, 
    -3px 0 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 -3px 2px #8c1b21/*, убираем 2 комментарий получаем обводку еще жирнее
    4px 4px 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 4px 2px #8c1b21, 
    -4px 0 2px #8c1b21, 
    0 -4px 2px #8c1b21
    */
}
```

```html
<p>ОБВОДКА ТЕКСТА</p>
```

Comment: Также мы можете воспользоваться каким либо генератором обводки текста с помощью css3, вот [этот сервис](https://protocoder.ru/css/strokeTextGen) к примеру

Comment: Как вариант, да. Если никто ничего лучше не предложит, приму Ваш ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот на `SVG` обводка текста

Проверил даже в IE11

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 388.37387 101.10015"><text transform="matrix(.78487 0 0 1.2741 193.902 -57.52)" y="105.312" x="-129.271" style="line-height:28.17656326px"; font-weight="700" font-size="54.099" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke="#d20925" stroke-width="2.145"><tspan style=' y="105.312" x="-129.271"'>text-border</tspan></text></svg>
```

Comment: круто очень! спасибо ) но я правильно понимаю, что в IE работать будет только от 11 версии и выше?

Comment: я на ниже версии не пробовал проверять -  у меня нету к сожалению Xp но пробовал на midori от ubuntu и тоже работало

Comment: родной эмулятор IE в верисии ниже 9 уже не отображает SVG

Answer (score 0):

Так годится?

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 4px red);
}
```

```html
<p>Обводка текста</p>
```

Comment: не-е (( нужна именно обводка букв, как outline - тень как раз не нужна